# Avoiding 'while' loop in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm wondering, whether it is possible to omit 'while' loop in this part of R code?

```
while (matrix[i] != -1){
        i = i+1
      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you want the new version to be functionally equivalent?

Comment: Yes, I want to optimize my code a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
i <- which(a==-1)[1]
```

`which(a==-1)` returns all the indices of the elements of the vector or matrix `a` which are equal to -1. You only want the first one, so take element 1 of the resulting array.

Note: this returns `NA` if the matrix `a` does not have any -1 element

Comment: how would it look like if 'a' was a vector? I mean 

while (vector[i] != -1){
        i = i+1
      }

Comment: It would look the same.

Comment: Specified in the answer